# Where can I find ubuntu one contacts for android?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, contacts

I'm able to stream my music to my android device but I still can't sync my contacts. It was impossible for me to find ubuntu one contacts in the android market and funambol doesn't seem to work. So where can i find this application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/?p=943
It explains why we can't sync our contacts with mobile devices ! 
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu one for Android website and the application can be found at this [web-location](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ubuntuone.android.files&feature=search_result).

[image]

The ubuntu one contacts app is visible only if you are running 2.x as described in the [ubuntu one wiki.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyCantISeeTheUbuntuOneContactsAppInTheAndroidMarketplace)

The [contacts app is provided by Funambol](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyIsntMyPhoneSupported) - if you are having problems then have a look at the [support blog for updates](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/)

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to work with contacts... It is said in ubuntu one website that I can sync my ubuntu one account with my android mobile phone, ubuntu one files isn't for contacts, is it ?

Comment: @user21368 - added more info.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the question on its own, but I thought I'd mention that I wrote to U1 support just now, asking them to update the U1 Mobile and U1 Contacts pages to reflect this being unavailable for the time being.

I find it an incredibly useful service even without the contacts, but people less forgiving might otherwise come away with the feeling it's a bait and switch, advertising a feature that's not there.

The link in the post above says it'll be available later this year in an approved form, which I'm looking forward to.